# Gnome-terminal access with in c

Tags: gnome-terminal, c

I'm trying to write a C program to open separate terminal and ping google.com

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char command[50];
strcpy(command,"gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "ping -c4 google.com"'");
system(command);

return (0);
}
```

But it only shows error message like this

> c2.c: In function ‘main’:
>   c2.c:9:43: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ping’
>   strcpy(command,"gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "ping -c4 google.com"'");

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would either have to escape the inner double quotes:

```
strcpy(command, "gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c \"ping -c4 google.com\"'");
```

or directly run the `ping` command in the terminal, without an enclosing shell:

```
strcpy(command, "gnome-terminal -e 'ping -c4 google.com'");
```

Please note that both variants will close the terminal window immediately after the `ping` command exits, because neither of them starts an interactive shell.

---

If you want the terminal to stay open and be able to enter commands, you must start an interactive shell after `ping` exits. I don't know why you pick `sh` (which points to `/bin/dash` in Ubuntu) instead of the standard Bash shell with more features, but that doesn't matter. Here's how you could do it:

```
strcpy(command, "gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c \"ping -c4 google.com ; sh\"'");
```

---

If you just want the window to stay open until it receives a keystroke (will not allow entering a command but exit immediately when you hit any key), you would run Bash's `read` command after your `ping`, e.g. like this:

```
strcpy(command, "gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"ping -c4 google.com ; read -s -n1\"'");
```

This suppresses the entered key from being echoed in the terminal and returns after the first entered character, not waiting for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. For more info about `read` type `help read` in a Bash shell.

Please note that this does not work in `sh` (Dash) because `read` is specific to Bash.

Comment: `strcpy(command, "gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c \"ping -c4 google.com\"'");             strcpy(command, "gnome-terminal -e 'ping -c4 google.com'");`                                              Both commands close window, I want to  prevent, to close the window after ping command exits.

Comment: Do you want to have an interactive shell prompt after `ping` exited, or do you just want the window to stay open without being able to enter commands?

Comment: I edited my answer to include options for both cases, but the second one requires you to use Bash.

Comment: It works awesome , you are Great Byte Commander